# Flutter: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code, Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos

I was trying to generate the ipa file to upload it on App Store, but it is generating this error: `Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign`. I've seen several related issues but nothing solved for me.
When I run `flutter build ios --no-codesign`, the build runs successfully, but when I try to archive the app through Xcode the same error occurs.

End of log where it shows the error. `flutter build ipa --verbose`

```
         [  +16 ms] Done persisting file store
                        [  +58 ms] "flutter assemble" took 118.784ms.
                        [   +8 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 6ms
                        [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
                        [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
                        [   +2 ms] exiting with code 1
                        [  +16 ms] Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign

/Users/desenvolvimento/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dffkukvjlzgxndaqfjrozidwautj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runne
                        r/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter with identity F9A989857ED0BFDE1E07FD35D31A5767CF2D55E0.

/Users/desenvolvimento/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dffkukvjlzgxndaqfjrozidwautj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermed
                                   iates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter: errSecInternalComponent
                    
                                   #0      _signFramework (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/ios.dart:644:5)
                                   #1      UnpackIOS.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/ios.dart:295:5)
                                   #2      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:839:27)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #3      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:473:21)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #4      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:777:32)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #5      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:473:21)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #6      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:777:32)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #7      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:606:16)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #8      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:317:32)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1161:27)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #15     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #16     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #17     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                    
                        [   +4 ms] 
                                   #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
                                   #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:334:7)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1161:27)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                   #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                        Failed to package /Users/desenvolvimento/dev/projetos/app_hepta.
                        Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
                    
                    
                        Result bundle written to path:
                                /var/folders/sj/rm9165nj3cq7lzwz8_hnhc6w0000gp/T/flutter_tools.NCtQRd/flutter_ios_build_temp_diroJotH2/temporary_xcresult_bundle
                    
                    
[+7524 ms] "flutter ipa" took 263.857ms.
[   +8 ms] Encountered error while archiving for device.
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _BuildIOSSubCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:279:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      BuildIOSArchiveCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:122:50)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1161:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +271 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 253ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

**Flutter version: 2.10.2**   **Xcode version: 13.2.1**